# How can i rotate the FPSController to it's original rotation angle?

Tags: unity, c#

It should be kind of slowly standing effect.
The FPSController is starting at rotation: X = 7 Y = 112 Z = -31

[image: Rotation]

The problem is that i have on the FPSController a script that i use the mouse to rotate the camera around. And i see that when i rotate the camera the center point of the FPSController seems stuck on this angle even if i change the rotation to 0,0,0

If i start the game running it when the rotation of the FPSController is 0,0,0 then it's standing but when i start the game with 7,112,-31 and then moving the mouse it keep be locked on this rotation values. And i want it to slowly return to the original 0,0,0

I tried when the game is running and the fpscontroller rotation set to 7,112,-31 to change it to 0,0,0 but it keep staying at the rotation of 7,112,-31

What i want is that the fpcscontroller to stand. I don't think that i need to change it's position but only the rotation.

In my script i tried this:
At the top:

```
public FirstPersonController fpc;
public float speed = 10F;
```

Then in the Update:

```
void Update()
{
  fpc.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fpc.transform.rotation, 
  Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

But it didn't return it to the standing position it keep it on the current rotation 7,112,-31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I didn't get quite right your issue, but I'll try...Maybe you could store the initial rotation on **Awake:**

**Edit:** Now I got your issue. You are using the interpolation (Slerp) wrong. It is based on the formula:

> **P = P0 + (t * (P1 - P0)), 0 < t < 1**

So it is an interpolation normalized between 0 and 1, the problem with your function is that **(Time.deltaTime * speed)** is always giving a delta of frames duration (usually 0.02) multiplied by your speed, that is never going to reach 1 to have your rotation at the Quaternion.identity. You should play with a float that each frame gets summed until it reaches 1, giving a quick example:

```
Quaternion initialRotation; /// <summary>Here you store the initial rotation.</summary>
float t = 0.0f; /// <summary>Time reference for the interpolation.</summary>

/// <summary>Called on MonoBehaviour initialization.</summary>
void Awake()
{
    initialRotation = transform.rotation;
}

/// <summary>This MonoBehaviour's Tick at each frame.</summary>
void Update()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(initialRotation, Quaternion.identity, t);
    t += (Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

So you could use that value initialized on Awake, the slerp takes that rotation, since interpolating between the actual rotation wouldn't give the expected results. We are using **Quaternions** here, since what there is shown on the inspector is an Euler Angle representation of the quaternion, and its less recomended to play with **eulerAngles**. So, if you want your FPC to be at a (0,0,0) rotation, then set its transform.rotation to **Quaternion.identity**.