# Camera rotate at target?

Tags: unity

I have free camera that move and rotate around the level. In this script if tb = true, I want my camera to rotate at target. Camera will show my character not rotate at character direction. [image](https://d2ujflorbtfzji.cloudfront.net/package-screenshot/a2044248-5313-4572-a917-824e0d0ed804_scaled.jpg)

```
public Transform avatar1; // character
public Camera cam;
public bool tb;

void Start()
{
    tb = false;
}

void Update()
{

    if (tb == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(bu1());
    }

}

IEnumerator bu1()
{
    cam.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(cam.transform.position, new Vector3(avatar1.transform.position.x + 6, 10, avatar1.transform.position.z + 7), 0.1f);
    cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(cam.transform.rotation, avatar1.transform.rotation, 0.4f); // here is my problem
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    tb = false;

}
```

Comment: just search for unity transform.lookat() with lerping

Answer (score 1):

You are lerping the camera's rotation to the target's rotation, you want the camera to rotate towards the player, you need a direction vector that points towards that target, to do that:

> **direction = target - observer** (all are vectors)

After getting the direction, you need to convert that vector to a quaternion, since that is how rotation works, for that, there is already a function that makes that conversion (Quaternion.Euler).

Example:

```
public Transform avatar1; // character
public Camera cam;
public bool tb;
public float duration = 2f; /// Lerping duration.

void Start()
{
    tb = false;
}

void Update()
{

    if (tb == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(bu1());
    }

}

IEnumerator bu1()
{
    float n = 0.0f; /// Normalized time reference.
    Vector3 direction = avatar1.position - cam.transform.position;
    Quaternion originalRotation = cam.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(direction);

    cam.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(cam.transform.position, new Vector3(avatar1.position.x + 6, 10, avatar1.position.z + 7), 0.1f); 

    while(n < 1.0f)
    {
         cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(cam.transform.rotation, newRotation, n);
         n += (Time.deltaTime / duration);
         yield return null;
    }

    tb = false;
}

/// You can also use Quaternion.LookRotation(newRotation);
```

As a side note, your avatar is already a Transform, so it is not necessary to call "avatar1.transform.position", instead you can just call "avatar1.position".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your notes and your script. But still this didn't solve the problem Here what i got [Image](https://s33.postimg.cc/uou6z5vxb/image.png). As, you see, Camera doesn't look at player. I need this camera rotate to face character it self [Image](https://s33.postimg.cc/3r09xevun/000.png).

Comment: Then it is a matter of the time parameter you are passing on Quaternion.Lerp, try putting it on 1f, just as a proof that it does work. Since you have it on 0.4f, it means that it will make 40% of the rotation it should do. See this post I answered as a reference of how Lerping works: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150436/how-can-i-rotate-the-fpscontroller-to-its-original-rotation-angle/150443#150443

Comment: I modified the answer already, so you can get the point of the last comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @LinkWindcrafter for you respond and trying to help me. Your new script didn't change thing it gives the same result. Maybe I didn't explain my point in good way. Now, I get solution for my camera and I will post it. Thank you again.

Comment: It looks like you want `Quaternion.LookRotation`, which takes a `Vector3` representing a directional offset in Cartesian coordinates and returns a quaternion that looks in that direction. `Quaternion.Euler` takes a `Vector3` representing an Euler angle triplet. So if the object is 180 units away along the x axis, `Quaternion.LookRotation` will return a quaternion facing along the x axis, while `Quaternion.Euler` will return a quaternion looking along the negative z axis, upside-down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution part.

```
IEnumerator bu1()
{

    cam.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(cam.transform.position, new Vector3(avatar1.transform.position.x + 6, 10, avatar1.transform.position.z + 7), 0.1f);
   var CamRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(avatar1.transform.position - cam.transform.position);
    cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(cam.transform.rotation , CamRot, 4 * Time.deltaTime);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    tb = false;

}
```